# Find sum of $\sum_{i=1}^{8}$ $\sum_{j=1}^{10}$ $(2i+2j)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, notation

The question is how to find $\sum_{i=1}^{8}$ $\sum_{j=1}^{10}$ $(2i+2j)$.

So I worked inside out, and split the inside sum into two as such:

$2\sum_{j=1}^{10} i +     2\sum_{j=1}^{10} j$

Second one I used the formula $n(n+1)/2$
and got $55 *2 = 110$

First One is just $2i$

So then I placed that into the outside sum and got:

$\sum_{i=1}^{8} {(110+2i)}$

$2 \sum_{i=1}^{8} i + 110 \sum_{i=1}^{8}$

Which is $n(n+1)/2$

$36*2 = 72 + 110 
= 182$

Is 182 the correct answer here? I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven´t considered $\sum_{j=1}^{10} 2i=20i$.

In total it is $\sum_{i=1}^{8} (20i+110)=20\sum_{i=1}^{8} i+110\sum_{i=1}^{8} 1$

$=\frac{8\cdot 9}{2}\cdot 20+110\cdot 8= 720+880=1600$

**Edit:** Pay attention on $\sum_{i=1}^8 110=110\cdot \sum_{i=1}^8 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^8 1=8$, it is **not** **1**.

Comment: can you explain how the last part is equal to 8, not 1?

Comment: @user20842454566 You have 8 summands, because the index goes from 1 to 8. Each summand is fix, because it doesn´t change with the value of the index i. The value of the summands is always 1. Therefore $\sum_{i=1}^8 1=1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=8$

Comment: @user20842454566 You are welcome.

Comment: Just one more question to clear things up if you don't mind, if the index start at 0 and ended at 8, would that be 9 summands? in the 8 Summands example you showed me just now.

Comment: Yes, you´re right. It is also right, that $\sum_{i=5}^{13} 1=9$. The constant 1 just doesn´t care about the value of the index.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that is not right. Another way to do it may be
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{10}(2i + 2j)=2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{10}i + 2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{10}j=20\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}i + 16\sum\limits_{j=1}^{10}j=\\=20\frac{8*9}{2} + 16\frac{10*11}{2}=720+880=1600
$$

Comment: I was trying to follow the answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173498/simple-double-summation.

Comment: Can you explain what I did wrong exactly?

Comment: @user20842454566 I did.  But if you do not want to read my answer, it is o.k.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^8 \sum_{j=1}^{10} i = \sum_{j=1}^{10} \left( \sum_{i=1}^8 i \right) = 10  \sum_{i=1}^8 i $. Similarly for the other term.